# Предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Имеются скромные три строчки плюсового кода, написанные в VS 2015

```
std::list <sf::TcpSocket> soc;
sf::TcpSocket co;
soc.push_back(co);
```

На этапе сборки возникает ошибка следующего вида

> error C2280: "sf::TcpSocket::TcpSocket(const sf::TcpSocket &)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию

Ошибку такую вижу впервые, в ранних версиях VS не сталкивался, нашел код ошибки на MSDN, однако ничего внятного там не увидел. Что за зверь такой и как бороться?

Comment: а что такое `sf::TcpSocket` - ваш класс? похоже у него нет конструктора по умолчанию.

Comment: Нет, класс не мой, конструктор по умолчанию есть

Comment: как ниже уже написали, там не только конструктор по умолчанию нужен, но и копирования.

Думаю я , что Вам нужен обычный shared_ptr.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У класса sf::TcpSocket нет конструктора копирования. Вы уверены что нужно хранить объекты, а не указатели?

```
std::list<sf::TcpSocket*> soc;
sf::TcpSocket *co = new sf::TcpSocket();
soc.push_back(co);
```

Если sf::TcpSocket - Ваш класс и Вы уверенны, что в списке нужно хранить именно экземпляры класса, а не указатели на них. то нужно определить конструктор копирования:

```
sf::TcpSocket::TcpSocket(const sf::TcpSocket &other)
{
    //тут копируем нужные нам объекты
}
```

Comment: Необходимо хранить именно объекты, а не указатели на них. Т.к. код выглядит примерно так.
while (running) {
  //Те 3 строчик
}
Т.е. с каждой итерацией объект будет удалятся, в случае если я буду помещать указатели, они станут ссылаться на уже удаленный объект.

Comment: Почему они будут ссылаться на удаленный объект? если создачть через new, а delete не вызывать, то ничего и не будет удалено.

Comment: Сейчас совсем стыдный вопрос задам, в дальнейшем удаление из списка произойдет корректно?

Comment: @Jereli  я описал как именно решить Вашу проблему компиляции. Если класс sf::TcpSocket - реализован Вами, то Вам решать какую логику он будет использовать. Но обычно, класс TcpSocket(работа с сетью) не подразумевает возможность копирования, которое происходит при помещение элемента в std::list. По-этому, более логично было бы помещать в список именно указатели. ну и конечно же не забывать их корректно удалять, когда это нужно.

Comment: `в дальнейшем удаление из списка произойдет корректно` - никаких проблем с удалением не вижу. Разве что попытаетесь дважды удалить один и тот же объект.

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с `c++11` для типов, хранимых в `std::vector`, [не требуется](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) обязательного наличия копирующего конструктора. При этом, правда, потребуется перемещающий.

В случае с Вашим `sf::TcpSocket` это, конечно, не поможет (судя по [описанию](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0-fr/classsf_1_1TcpSocket.php)), но в определенных ситуациях может быть полезным.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    S() { std::cout << "def ctor\n"; }
    S(const S&) = delete;
    S(S&&) { std::cout << "mv ctor\n"; }
    void f() const { std::cout << "f()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<S> v;
    v.push_back(S{});
    for(auto& s: v) {
        s.f();
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Результат выполнения](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vfTrMgEJMPU6K752)</kbd>